# Update accounts table with the user preferences in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have the following SQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        'experience' enum('Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced) NULL, Default Beginner,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, 'experience') VALUES (1, 'test', '$2y$10$SfhYIDtn.iOuCW7zfoFLuuZHX6lja4lF4XA4JqNmpiH/.P3zB8JCa', 'test@test.com');
```

And besides this, I also have a registration form that will populate the database with the given values using a registration form.

And the following HTML form which will be the update form:

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="register">
        <h1>Update My Preferences</h1>
        <form action="update_preferences.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <select name="new_experience" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="">Change Investment Experience</option>
                    <option>Beginner</option>
                    <option>Intermediate</option>
                    <option>Advanced</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- form-group end.// -->
            <label for="username">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="new_username" value="<?=$_SESSION['name']?>" id="username">
            <label for="password">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="new_password" placeholder="" value="" id="password">
            <label for="email">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="email" name="new_email" value="<?=$email?>" id="email">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I manage to add the following code for `update_preferences.php` but then I got stuck with the error "Could not prepare statement!
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in /home2/freemark/public_html/update_preferences.php on line 71":

```
<?php
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogindb';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check if the data exists.
if (!isset($_POST['new_experience'], $_POST['new_username'], $_POST['new_password'], $_POST['new_email'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please complete the registration form!');
}
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
if (empty($_POST['new_experience']) || empty($_POST['new_username']) || empty($_POST['new_password']) || empty($_POST['new_email'])) {
    // One or more values are empty.
    die ('Please complete the registration form');
}

$new_exp_level=$_POST['new_experience'];
$new_username=$_POST['new_username'];
$new_password=$_POST['new_password'];
$new_email=$_POST['new_email'];

// We need to check if the account with that username exists.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {

    if (!filter_var($_POST['new_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die ('Email is not valid!');
    }

    if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['new_username']) == 0) {
    die ('Username is not valid!');
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['new_password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['new_password']) < 5) {
    die ('Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long!');
    }

    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['new_username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // Username already exists
        echo 'Username exists, please choose another!';
    } else {
        // Username doesnt exists, insert new account
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE accounts SET $new_exp_level = ?, $new_username = ?, $new_password = ?, $new_email = ? WHERE id = ?')) {
        // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
        $password = password_hash($_POST['new_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['new_username'], $password, $_POST['new_email'], $_POST['new_experience']);
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location: login.html');
        exit();
        echo 'You have successfully registered, you can now login!';
    } 

    else {
        // Something is wrong with the sql statement, check to make sure accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
        echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
    }
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    // Something is wrong with the sql statement, check to make sure accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Got stuck with __what__?

Comment: @mark02 Please use the `edit` button if you want to update your question.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is....

Comment: The error is :"Could not prepare statement! Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in /home2/freemark/public_html/update_preferences.php on line 71":

Comment: I can suggest you to use `PDO` instead of `mysqli` driver for db operations, your code will be more readable and will make the debug faster than mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you stuck at but query for multiple fields updating looks like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?, field3 = ? WHERE id = ?";
// binding values can be done something like
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $_SESSION['id']);
```

Also, read [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) about password hashing and **never** store plain passwords.

Comment: Something i'm missing from this, but I'm not yet figure it out what is missing or if it is the correct approach
`
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE accounts SET $new_exp_level = ?, $new_username = ?, $new_password = ?, $new_email = ? WHERE id = ?')) {
  // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
  $password = password_hash($_POST['new_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['new_experience'],$_POST['new_username'], $password, $_POST['new_email']);
  $stmt->execute();
`

Comment: Your field name is __not__ `$new_email`. Your field name is __`email`__, see the difference? Same to other fields like `username`, `password` etc. `$new_email` is a __variable__ which stores a value.

Comment: In prepare or bind_param or in both ? but anyway this ' $_POST['new_email']' suppose to get the value from the new email update form(<input type="email" name="new_email" value="<?=$email?>" id="email">) right?

Comment: In sql query in `prepare` and yes, `$_POST['new_email']` stores value from form fields. If you don't know what is stored in a variable - use debugging functions like `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: You're right, I see now, but now I'm getting this "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home2/freemark/public_html/update_preferences.php on line 59

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/freemark/public_html/update_preferences.php:59) in /home2/freemark/public_html/update_preferences.php on line 61"

Comment: Okay, this error happens not with you so you can easily find an answer here by using __search__.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $_POST['experience'])
username,password,email and experience are all strings , and I'm binding 4 parameters

Comment: Please __review your code carefully__. I don't see what you're doing, so I can only guess - you forgot `id`?

Comment: Also if you have any other questions - __create a new question__ and don't increase number of comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($new_password){
```

is missing a closing bracket

```
if(empty($new_password) *)*{
```

since your update your error is here:

```
else {
        // Something is wrong with the sql statement, check to make sure accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
        echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
    }
    }
    $stmt->close(); <-- this is line 71 (after pasting your code into my IDE so i assume it's the full content)
```

so `$stmt` does not have a method called `'close`'.  this should, I think, say `$con->close();`

really, if an error is point you to an exact line with an exact message, it shouldn't be too difficult to debug
-- update--

Also i just noticed you're not binding enough parameters

```
UPDATE accounts SET $new_exp_level = ?, $new_username = ?, $new_password = ?, $new_email = ? WHERE id = ? //<-- 5 placeholders

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['new_username'], $password, $_POST['new_email'], $_POST['new_experience']); // <-- 4 params
```